# Google Maps Weather Layer No Longer Works Since Google Update

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, weather-api

I understand that Google updated their map a day or two ago. Since the update, the weather layer no longer works on the webpage I am building.  I have a MacBook Air with Apache server installed.

When the map loads the marker still works and the latitude and longitude are correct, but the city names no longer show nor does any of the weather features.

Here is what I have tried to fix the issue: 
* I tried the three different web browsers that I have installed on my MacBook - Firefox, Safari, Google. Same issue in all three.
* I tried turning my Mac off and back on again. 
* I went to the Google maps API website and according to that my coding is correct.
* If I do set the zoom property to 13, the city names will show up but no weather layer...which I understand is the proper behavior with a zoom setting of 13 or higher. 
* On the Google maps API website, I copied and pasted the example code for the weather layer and it worked!  They have a latitude and longitude of a country outside of the USA.  I compared my coding to the example coding and my coding is the same, except for the latitude and longitude.  SO, when I changed the latitude and longitude in the example coding to another location the weather layer stopped working.

Here is my code, but it seems to me that the issue is on Google's end.  It was suggested that I post the question here (I already posted this question at productforums.google.com) because employee's from Google will see this question.

```
var map;

      function initialize() 
      {
        var mapOptions = 
        {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0157394, -105.2792435),
          /*center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.265984,-123.127491),*/
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          mapTypeControl: true,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
          },
          zoomControl: true,
          zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
          } 
        }; 

         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), mapOptions); 


         /* Weather */
         var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
           temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT
          });

         weatherLayer.setMap(map);

         var cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
         cloudLayer.setMap(map);


         /* Marker & InfoWindow */   
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
          {
           position: mapOptions.center,
           map: map
           });

           var text = '<div id="mapText">' + 'I live in beautiful Boulder, CO!' + '</div>';  

        var infowin = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
          {
           content: text,
           pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 20)
          }); 

          infowin.open(map, marker);

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
          {
            infowin.open(map,marker);
          });
      };

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

To work around the issue for now, I set my zoom to 13 so at least the city and street names will show, and the weather features are disabled when zoom is set to 13 or higher.

I'm pretty sure my coding is correct. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like there is no weather data for the US, even in the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-weather).  Certainly seems to be an issue on Google's side, so not much we can help you with.  Perhaps create an [issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/)

Comment: @geocodezip - Ahhh, good to know that it's not just me.  Thanks for the issue tracker link...I will for sure create a ticket.  Thanks for your help.  :)

Comment: [Issue in issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6474)

Comment: I created a bug report on Google's website.  Here is the link if anyone wants to follow it:  
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6474&thanks=6474&ts=1394460611
@geocodezip - hahaha!  you beat me by 4 seconds posting the bug report I just filed.

Comment: @jlivni - You're welcome.  Thanks for confirming.

Comment: This issue was resolved earlier today.  Thanks again for reporting it (here and on the issue tracker).